# taking a screenshot with scrapy-selenium

Tags: python, scrapy-selenium

been trying to get scrapy-selenium to work for a while, I have the simple code from the tutorial and just trying to take a screenshot but for some reason I don't get a proper response, here is my code:

```
from shutil import which

SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'firefox'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = which('geckodriver')
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['-headless']  # '--headless' if         
using chrome instead of firefox

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800
}

from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest


def start():
    yield SeleniumRequest(
        url='www.google.com',
        callback=parse_result, wait_time=1000,
        screenshot=True
   )

def parse_result(self, response):
    print(response.meta)
    with open('image.png', 'wb') as image_file:
        image_file.write(response.meta['screenshot'])


start()
```

I am getting no screenshot key in response.meta..
what am I missing ? by the way I am using python 3.10
Thanks in advance :)